# how can i view these files in the right encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, gzip

http://ftp.monash.edu.au/pub/nihongo/examples.gz
http://ftp.monash.edu.au/pub/nihongo/edict.gz

no matter what encoding i view these pages in, all but the english is garbled.

i tried:

UTF-8
Western (ISO-8859-1)
Japanese (Shift_JIS)
Japanese (EUC-JP)
Japanese (ISO-2022-JP)

i even downloaded them extracted, opened with notepad++ and tried all the charset encodings with that too. Always garbled.  it should show the japanese, and then then english word with desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try auto-detect provided by browsers, for example, Chrome detected GBK for Chinese for me, and showed the page correctly.

Comment: omg, that one works, why on earth is japanese text encoded in Chinese encoding?

Comment: @user1397417 because all oriental languages look the same? By the way, remember to accept my answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: i have worker with japanese alot and this is the first time i have seen this

Comment: i just noticed now, when studying some entries. its actually not correct in that GBK chinese encoding. the hiragana is correct, but the kanji(chinese characters) used by both japanese and chinese, are not correct. not one match has the correct kanji in that encoding.

Comment: found it, its Japanese (EUC-JP), used the auto detect, it took a long time to auto detect the right one but it did it.

Comment: @user1397417 but you said in your question it did not work.